# Adding a newline in TextView with String from database

Tags: android, sqlite, textview

I have an SQLite database where some of the values contain strings with the newline `'\n'` character. I was hoping that when that value was pulled from the database, put into a `String` and a `TextView`'s `setText()` was set to the `String` value, the newlines would work, but unfortunately it does not. Any other options other than having to parse the string and break it up manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you debug, you will see that the string is actually "\ \r\ \n" or "\ \n", ie, it is escaped. So if you massage that string, to get rid of the extra \, you will have your solution. This is true especially if you are reading from a database.

Answer (score 1):

your string is being escaped when it is put into the database. You could try and unescape the string by calling String s = unescape(stringFromDatabase) before you place it in your TextView.

---

> private String unescape(String description)  {
>       return description.replaceAll("\\n", "\\n"); }

As a side note, make sure you are using DatabaseUtils.sqlEscapeString() on any kind of data that is from the user or an unknown changeable source when inserting data into the database. This will protect you from errors and SQL Injection.